# cannot select a subset in a range in vba

Tags: excel, vba, range, subset

When I use Range keyword to select a group of cells it works 
Ex: `Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(3, 3)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3` - works fine

but when do a similar thing using a variable then it only highlights the last element
Ex:

```
Set GraphCells = Range("D10:FO12")    
GraphCells(Cells(1, 2), Cells(3, 3)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

This highlights only `cell(3,3)`

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Range method.

```
Set GraphCells = Range("A10:E1100")
GraphCells.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(3, 3)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```